# Visual Studio Output Window Font Size tracks with Code Window. Then it doesn't

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I've seen this for years with Visual Studio and would like to finally understand it.

I'll be coding in VS and I want to increase my text editor font size.  My typical method is to use use CTRL+MOUSEWHEEL to increase it.  As text in text editor gets bigger, so does the text in the Output Window.  They're sync-ed.

That makes the output window font size larger than I want so then I go to...

```
Tools >> Options >> Environment >> Fonts and Colors
```

...change the category to "Output Window" and change the font size.  And yes, that certainly works.  But it has the odd side-effect of making the output window stop tracking with the code window.  Now, if I use CTRL+MOUSEWHEEL to adjust the code window font size, the output window does not change.

But then, a month or two later, I will notice that they're tracking together again.

What is it that made the two track together?  Is there any way to toggle that tracking on and off?

(Both windows use "Courier New" for a font, if that matters)

Comment: Weird! Only ever had editor text zoom in/out like this with output window text size remaining constant. Have you got any extensions installed that may interfere with this?

Comment: N.B. I tend to use different fonts Fira Code size 10 (text editor) and Consolas size 9 (default - output window). I tried setting them both the same, but still didn't see this behaviour.

Comment: I do have a couple of extensions but enabling/disabling them appears to have no effect on this